# AST eclipse, adding arguments to a MethodInvocation

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

Im trying to add arguments to the arguments list of a MethodInvocation and it doesnt seem to work, I can remove objects but I cant see to add them.
My end goal is to take 2 MethodInvocation that invoke the same method with different arguments and convert it to 1 MethodInvocation that has a ConditionalExpression as an argument.
Example:

```
if (A){
   System.out.println("hi");
} else {
   System.out.println("hey");
}
```

Will be converted to:

```
System.out.println((A ? "hi" : "hey"));
```

So I would also appreciate it if someone knwos how to convert the argument list to 1 big Expression I can place in the ConditionalExpression.

Thanks!

EDIT: sorry forgot to mention is it a code formatting plug-in for ecplise

EDIT2: the code I am trying to run:

```
final ExpressionStatement thenStmnt=(ExpressionStatement)((Block)node.getThenStatement()).statements().get(0),
            elseStmnt=(ExpressionStatement)((Block)node.getElseStatement()).statements().get(0);
MethodInvocation thenMethod=(MethodInvocation)thenStmnt.getExpression(),
                elseMethod=(MethodInvocation)elseStmnt.getExpression();
final MethodInvocation method=ast.newMethodInvocation();
method.setName(ast.newSimpleName("add"));
method.arguments().add(0, elseMethod.arguments().get(0));
```

ast is a given leagal AST and node is a given leagal IfStatement.

Comment: Do you want to call `Met3(Met1(param1),Met1(param2));` like this?

Comment: if by Met you mean method then no.
What I want to do is exactly what is says in the example I gave.
My main problem is how to add arguemtn to MethodInvocation, I think I will be from here if you can tell me how to do this.

Comment: Could you please put an example, no problem even if wrong, so that it could be more clear about what you want?

Comment: I added the code I am trying to run, is that what you ment?

Comment: Solved it, i'll add an answer in 8 hours because it appears I can only answer my question 8 hours from now o_0

Comment: hi Tomer.z can you please post your answer , as u are able to solve. I am having same problem how to pass arguments to MethodInvocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, problem was here:

```
method.arguments().add(0, elseMethod.arguments().get(0));
```

If you want to take or copy something that is already part of your original code, meaning already exist in the AST you have to use r.createCopyTarget, like so:

```
method.arguments().add(0, r.createCopyTarget(elseMethod.arguments().get(0)));
```